# how to zip particular folders in linux using shell

Tags: linux, shell, zip, sh

Let say we have a directory structure like:

```
A
|---B
|   |---C
|   |   |--f1.txt
|   |
|   |---D
|   |   |--f2.txt
|
|---E
|   |---f3.txt
|   |
|
|---F
|   |---f4.txt
```

Now how to zip a file BE.zip excluding F directory, i.e when I unzip BE.zip the result should be:

```
|---B
|   |---C
|   |   |--f1.txt
|   |
|   |---D
|   |   |--f2.txt
|   
|---E
|   |---f3.txt
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ok got it..

```
zip -r BE.zip B/ E/
```

Answer (score -1):

you can u this for recursive

zip BE.zip B/* E/*